# How to get next working day with the input of number of days?

Tags: c#, winforms, date

I set up some methods to get holidays and used them to calculate next working day. This works fine but it only adds 1 day and gets the next non holiday weekday. I want to get the number of days by input and increment that date according to input and get the nex non holiday weekday. I tried some things but couldnt get exactly what i want.

Edit: I am using a method to get the next working day, excluding weekends and holidays. But my equation does that by incrementing the date only by 1 day. I want that number of days to be my input from user, and add that number to the date, exclude weekends and holidays and get the next working day. (My issue is on the adding that different number from my textbox)

```
public static DateTime GetWorkingDay(DateTime date, IList<Holiday> holidays, IList<DayOfWeek> weekendDays)

    {
        date = date.Date.AddDays(1);

        var holidayDates = holidays.Select(x => x.GetDate(date.Year))
            .Union(holidays.Select(x => x.GetDate(date.Year + 1)))
            .Where(x => x != null)
            .Select(x => x.Value)
            .OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();

        while (true)
        {
            if (weekendDays.Contains(date.DayOfWeek) || holidayDates.Contains(date))
                date = date.AddDays(1);
            else
                return date;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't your GetWorkingDay function have this "number of days" thing to be a passed parameter?

Comment: I dont know if it should. Thats why im asking. How can i add that parameter. Right now it only adds 1 day, Im trying to do that in another method but i think it should be done in GetWorkingDay like you said.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your `while` loop to (assuming `numDays` is your input):

```
while (numDays > 0)
{
    date = date.AddDays(1);

    if (!weekendDays.Contains(date.DayOfWeek) && !holidayDates.Contains(date))
        numDays--;  // Only decrement numDays if it's a working day.
}
```

Then return the date after the loop. You might want to assert that `numDays` isn't negative.

Comment: Sorry but that didnt work for me. It still added 1 day and calculated. Also with your loop it returns the weekend days also. Can you suggest something else?

Comment: @Mert You aren't being clear with your question or the issue you are having.

Comment: @LarsTech okay let me edit my question

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that might help. Or it might seem like total overkill. You decide.

Instead of trying to add one day at a time, figure out if it's a holiday, weekday, etc., just create a list of dates that you can query. That will make the logic much easier to understand, especially if you find yourself having to write more and more queries like this.

Ideally this is something you'd want to create once and keep around. It wouldn't make sense to keep creating this over and over.

Here's a stab at it:

```
public class Calendar
{
    private readonly List<CalendarDate> _dates = new List<CalendarDate>();

    public Calendar(
        DateTime startDate, 
        int length, 
        ICollection<DateTime> holidays,
        ICollection<DayOfWeek> weekDays)
    {
        if(length < 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(length), "The minimum length is one day.");

        for (var x = 0; x < length; x++)
        {
            var addingDate = new CalendarDate
            {
                RepresentedDate = startDate.Date.AddDays(x),
            };
            addingDate.IsHoliday = holidays.Contains(addingDate.RepresentedDate);
            addingDate.IsWeekday = weekDays.Contains(addingDate.RepresentedDate.DayOfWeek);
            _dates.Add(addingDate);
        }

        FirstDay = startDate.Date;
        LastDay = FirstDay.AddDays(length - 1);
    }

    public DateTime FirstDay { get; }
    public DateTime LastDay { get; }

    private class CalendarDate
    {
        internal DateTime RepresentedDate { get; set; }
        internal bool IsHoliday { get; set; }
        internal bool IsWeekday { get; set; }
        internal bool IsWorkingDay => !(IsHoliday || IsWeekday);
    }

    public DateTime GetNextWorkingDay(DateTime date)
    {
        date = date.Date;
        ValidateDateIsInRange(date);
        var result = _dates.FirstOrDefault(d => 
            d.RepresentedDate >= date && d.IsWorkingDay);
        if (result != null) return result.RepresentedDate;
        throw new InvalidOperationException("The result is outside the range of the calendar.");
    }

    private void ValidateDateIsInRange(DateTime date)
    {
        if(date < FirstDay || date > LastDay)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The specified date is outside the range of the calendar.");
    }
}
```

It admittedly looks like more work and more code. But the result is that once the data is in place, the calculation you're trying to do becomes very easy. So do all sorts of other calculations and queries, because now such functions can be written to reflect the questions that you're asking, like "What is the first date that matches this criteria?"

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I couldnt understand that fully but im trying to get my head around it. I will reply to you when i work it out.

Comment: I'd emphasize only using it if you think it helps. Incrementing one date at a time (what you started with) is a valid approach. Or what I've suggested might lead to something entirely different and better. If I was using this for real chances are it would go through some refinement.